# FancyBox Images in iframe are not responsive on mobile devices

Tags: jquery, image, iframe, fancybox, fancybox-2

I have a little problem. I need to create a gallery,
where embed youtube-videos an normal images
are shown. To get the arrows working between images and the video,
I have to use the iframe Modus. So I ended up with this:

```
<a href="url_of_embed_yt_vid" class="fancygal" rel="group"><img src="preview_for_vid"></a>
<a class="fancygal" rel="group" href="link_to_image"><img src="myimage"></a>


$('.fancygal').fancybox({
        'type'  : 'iframe',
        'scrolling' : 'no',
        'fitToView': true,
        'iframe' : {
                    'scrolling' : 'no',
                    'preload'   : false
                }                  
});
```

It works perfectly, besides that on mobile devices the images are not scaled down to fit in the fancybox (the fancybox has the right size).
If I scale down my browser on laptop/desktop devices, the images scale down correctly.

Does anyone have an idea, what may be the problem?

Thanks
Sonic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Images doesn't have to use `iframe` mode, only the youtube videos so this script should work for both :

```
$(".fancygal").fancybox({
    // 'type'  : 'iframe', //no needed
    scrolling: 'no',
    fitToView: true,
    iframe: {
        scrolling: 'no',
        preload: false
    }
});
```

then set the class `fancygal` to **all** links AND the special class `fancybox.iframe` to youtube videos links only like :

```
<a class="fancygal fancybox.iframe" rel="group" href="{link to youtube 1}">youtube one</a>
<a class="fancygal fancybox.iframe" rel="group" href="{link to youtube 2}">youtube two</a>
<a class="fancygal" rel="group" href="{link to image 1}">image one</a>
<a class="fancygal" rel="group" href="{link to image 3}">image two</a>
... etc.
```

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/KcSE9/)**

Comment: Thanks, works like a charm! I didn't know, that such .iframe classes exist.

Comment: @Sonic750 Also, instead of the class `fancybox.iframe` you could use the (HTML5) `data-fancybox-type="iframe"` attribute