# How to resize Fancybox 2 iframe on window resize

Tags: jquery, html, css, iframe

How can I resize an iframe of Fancybox 2 when the browser window size changes?

By default i've set the fancybox iframe body height to

```
height: 322px;
```

I need it to chage when window size is smaller.

Specifically when window width is no more than 680px, iframe height should be

```
height: 339px;
```

and when window no more than 480px, iframe height should be

```
height: 584px;
```

With no scroll bars.

Comment: If you're only using your iframe for images, have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18334431/fancybox-images-in-iframe-are-not-responsive-on-mobile-devices

Comment: it's a login form that pops up, website is responsive

Comment: ok, found it: i needed to use «inline» type instead of «iframe»